# Existence of expectation implies bound on a sequence of conditional expectations?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Supposing that nonnegative random variable $X$ has finite expectation, is it true that we must have $\lim\sup_{a\rightarrow\infty}E\left(\frac{X}{a}\mid X>a\right)\leq C$ for some C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Counter-example: $$\int_a^{\infty}P(X>t)dt=e^{-\int_0^a\frac {G(t)} t\, dt}$$ where $G(a)$ is positive, $\liminf_{a\to\infty} G(a)=0$, $G(0)=0$, $\frac {G(t)}t$ non-increasing, not in $L^1$ and $0\le G'(0)\le 1$.

Comment: Okay, I don't get it, and I may be missing something basic. Maybe you can point out the error in the following: the expression above is $\mathbb{E}[X ~| X>a]$, and is upper bounded by $1$. the supremum of $\mathbb{E}[X/a ~| X>a]$ is then upper bounded by $1/a$, and the lim sup goes to $0$.

Comment: @stoch I updated the answer. The expression above is NOT $E(X|X>a)$ which is equal to $\frac {E(X;X>a)}{P(X>a)}$ and $E(X;X>a)=aP(X>a)+\text{expression from above}$.

Comment: Yeah, I see. I was having a big-ass brainfart. Thanks.